# reading regular expression for beginner

Tags: php, regex, validation, email

I've read basic regular expressions on different websites to study them. my problem is that I don't understand some of them. here is an example I'm looking at to validate an e-mail address from w3schools

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

I don't understand the part `[\w\-]+` from my own understanding it says "string that has at least a alphanumeric". can you give me a clear explanation of this?

Comment: use regular-expressions.info, they're a good site for regexp tutorials. You can also enter your regexp into http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, and then hover your mouse over each piece and it will explain it in a tooltip.

Comment: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) has an excellent (free) tutorial and is a good place to start.

Comment: FYI - that pattern will invalidate valid email addresses like `me+stackoverflow@example.com` or `me@example`. It will also pass invalid addresses like `hey look@this.thing over here`

Comment: [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) has been helpful for me to visualize what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) `[\w\-]` (or more accurately without the unnecessary escaping, `[\w-]`) means

1. `\w` - [Word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html); any letter, number or underscore character, or...
2. `-` any hyphen

Using `[\w-]+` means *"one or more letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens"*.

As mentioned in the comments above, don't use W3Schools. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is the best resource available (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

```
[\w\-]+
```

This means any word character (a-z and underscores) and hyphens `\-`, between one and unlimited times, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`

### Some good regex resources for learning:

> http://Regex101.com
>
> http://www.regular-expressions.info

Get to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the breakdown:

1. `\w` is a character class which simply means letters, numbers, plus underscore. In regex, this is short for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
2. `\w\-` adds the hyphen to the \w class (not sure why the hyphen is escaped)
3. `[\w\-]+` means repeat the pattern at least once. So, 9@email.com is valid, but @email.com is obviously not.

Also, depending on your use case, you may be interested in this discussion on SO about why relying on regexes to validate email addresses may be a bad idea:

> [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: The hyphen is probably escaped because most newbies (like the authors / editors over at W3Schools) think that a hyphen in a character class **always** defines a range

Comment: Got it. To the OP, avoid w3schools whenever possible.